# Most efficient way to get all permutations in c++

Tags: c++, combinations, permutation

I am trying to calculate a lot of combinations in C++. I came up with the following implement by myself, but its efficiency is not satisfactory. It takes more than 3 seconds to get C-18-2 (every 2 combination of 18), I believe this can be done in much less time.

```
 vector<vector<int>> Mytool::combo2(int len){
    MatrixXd ma = MatrixXd::Zero(len*len*len,2);
    int ind = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ;i<len;i++){
        for (int j = 0 ;j<len;j++){
                VectorXd v1(2);
                v1<<i,j;
                ma.row(ind) = v1;
                ind++;
        }   
    };
    ind = 0;
    vector<vector<int>> res;
    for (int i=0;i<ma.rows();i++){
        int num1 = ma(i,0);
        int num2 = ma(i,1);
        if (num1!=num2){
            vector<int> v1;
            v1.push_back(num1);
            v1.push_back(num2);
            sort(v1.begin(),v1.end());
            if (find(res.begin(),res.end(),v1)==res.end())
                res.push_back(v1);
        }
    }
    return res;
 }
```

Any hints or advise will be helpful. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stl way is to use `std::next_permutation`

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> res;
std::vector<int> v(size - 2, 0);
v.resize(size, 1); // vector you be sorted at start : here {0, .., 0, 1, 1}.
do {
     res.push_back(v);
} while (std::next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()));
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/iYN8gZ).

As  Matthieu M pointed out, it would be more efficient to do the works directly inside the *do while* loop.

Comment: I would point out that, if possible, it would be better to use this *iteratively* (ie, do the work inside `do/while`) rather than first *generating* and then *consuming*. It would obviate the need for `res` which may end up taking a lot of memory.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way as you use combination of 2 elements, you may use a double loop:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> res;

for (std::size_t i = 0; i != size; ++i) {
    for (std::size_t j = i + 1; j != size; ++j) {
        std::vector<int> v(size);
        v[i] = 1;
        v[j] = 1;
        res.push_back(v);
    }
}
```